# Dynamic Expression from the Property of the object of the class

Tags: c#, lambda

i'm starting to explore dynamic expressions, so please help me to solve one issue.
I have an object

```
    public class Categorisation{
       string Name{get;set;}
    }

    public class Client{
       public Categorisation Categorisation{get;set;}
}
```

All I need is to write a dynamic expression and call Categorisation.**Name**.Equals("A1") from Client object.

```
x=>x.Categorisation.Name.Equals("A1")
```

How can I do this using Expressions?

```
   var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Client));
   var prop = Expression.Property(param, typeof(Client).GetProperty("Categorisation"));
   var argument = Expression.Constant("A1");
   var method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(string) });
   var call = Expression.Call(prop, method);
   var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Client, bool>>(call, param);
```

Of course this code is wrong and I call method Equals from Categorisation property and not from Name of Categorisation. But how to invoke Name property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Client));
var prop = Expression.Property(param, typeof(Client).GetProperty("Categorisation"));
var namePropExpr = Expression.Property(prop, "Name");
var argument = Expression.Constant("A1");
var method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(string) });
var call = Expression.Call(namePropExpr, method, argument);
var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Client, bool>>(call, param);
```