# get/set a property by expression

Tags: c#, lambda

Trying to create a data access component by mapping fields from an an oracle database to properties on an object. I've created a base object that takes a type and is called like this...

```
public class Document : DataProviderBase<DataObjects.Document> 
{ 
    // code goes here... 
}
```

This base object has a method called `AddMapping` that maps database fields to properties like this...

```
this.AddMapping<int>("ATD_KEY", "Key")
```

In this case...

- **`int`** is the type of property
- **`ATD_KEY`** is the field name in the database
- **`Key`** is the property name on `DataObjects.Document`

The code uses...

```
typeof(<TParent>).GetProperty(<property name>)
```

..to get `PropertyInfo` which is used to get and set the property. 
While this is great, I would like to add a bit of type safety and lambda expressions to the `AddMapping` method. I'd like to do something like the following...

```
this.AddMapping<int>("ATD_KEY", o => o.Key)
```

..where `o` is of the type provided by `DataProviderBase`. This will ensure that property `Key` is actually of type `int` and ensures that the string `"Key"` is not misspelt or the wrong case as is a problem with the current working code shown in the 1st `AddMapping` method.

Is this possible? if so how?

The closest example I've found is this 
[Dynamic Expression from the Property of the object of the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777290/dynamic-expression-from-the-property-of-the-object-of-the-class), however this still refers to the property by string and not by expression.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what are you trying to achieve: could you please clarify your question and any practical merits of expected solution? Thanks and regards,

Comment: The aim here is type safty. Property names in the previous method are consistantly miss-spelt and cause errors. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
public void AddMapping<T>(fieldName, Expression<Func<TParent, T>> propExpr)
{
    var memberExpr = (MemberExpression)propExpr.Body;
    PropertyInfo property = (PropertyInfo)memberExpr.Member;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible:

```
public static PropertyInfo GetProperty<TParent>(Expression<Func<TParent, object>> prop)
{
    var expr = prop.Body;

    if (expr.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
        expr = ((UnaryExpression)expr).Operand;

    if (expr.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        return ((MemberExpression)expr).Member as PropertyInfo;

    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid lambda", "prop");
}

public void AddMapping<TParent>(fieldName, Expression<Func<TParent, object>> prop)
{
    AddMapping(fieldName, GetProperty(prop).Name);
}
```

This method has the advantage of requiring only one type parameter (`TParent`). You pass in a lambda that may contain a cast into the property type. We get rid of that, and then get the member expression.